# Log a request to external API

Tags: php, symfony

I am calling an external API like this:

```
$transfer  = $apiTransfer->payment->fetch($respObj->id)->transfers(array('transfers' => [ ['account' => $dbres[0]['account_id']]]));
```

I want to see how the request parameters are sent. How do I do it?

**Edit**

The method in external API's file:

```
public function transfer($attributes = array())
{
    $relativeUrl = $this->getEntityUrl() . $this->id . '/transfers';
    print_r($attributes);
    exit;
    return $this->request('POST', $relativeUrl, $attributes);
}
```

Comment: You could use your browser's network tools -> network monitor -> request details

Comment: @jibsteroos this is a request made on the server side, so browser dev tools know nothing about it.

Comment: _“How do I do it?”_ - analyze the code, and figure out where it actually makes the HTTP request. No one here can tell you that, based on that one single line of code.

Comment: @misorude what do you mean by "where it makes the request"?

Comment: Well the point where the _actual_ HTTP request to the external API gets made … You are just calling some methods in the single line of code you have shown, doing that must result in an HTTP request being made _somewhere_ in the code. So if you want to know what actual parameters are send with that request, you first of all need to figure out where it gets actually made.

Comment: @misorude  i found the file of the external api where calling the method makes a http request. I tried to print the `attributes` that i think it uses as parameters for the request. I will edit the question to post their code. I am not even a php dev btw. pleae be gentle

Comment: @misorude I don't see anything when I print that

Comment: Impossible to tell how/if that even relates directly to the initial line of code you have shown. (`transfers` and `transfer` are different things.)

Comment: @misorude yeah..i was calling the wrong method